# Have the machine got invoiced by factory?

Tags: grammar

I want know the current status of invoicing:

> Have the machine got invoiced by factory?

Is this grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

As written it sounds like a machine is receiving an invoice from the factory, which doesn't make sense to me.

Maybe you meant something like...

- Have you received an invoice from the factory?
- Has the factory sent an invoice for the machine?

Comment: has the factory invoiced the machine?.....what about this...?

Comment: I believe that would imply that the machine is going to pay the invoice.